# Tcl regexp not returning all matches

Tags: regex, tcl

I am reading a file, the content is as below:

```
 Aug2017:
 --------------------------------------
   Name   Age   Phone
 --------------------------------------
   Jack   25    128736372
   Peter  26    987840392
 --------------------------------------
 Sep2017:
 --------------------------------------
   Name   Age   Phone
 --------------------------------------
   Jared  21    874892032
   Eric   24    847938427
 --------------------------------------
```

So I wanted to extract the information between every dashed line and put them into a list. Assuming `$data` is containing the file content, I am using the tcl regexp below to extract the info:

```
regexp -all -inline -- {\s+\-{2,}\s+(.*?)\s+\-{2,}\s+} $data
```

As I know, the returned matched result will be stored as a list that containing `fullMatch` and `subMatch`.

I double checked with `llength` command, there is only one `fullMatch` and `subMatch`.

```
llength $data
2
```

Why is there only 1 `subMatch`? There supposed to be 5 matches like below:

```
 Aug2017:
 --------------------------------------
   Name   Age   Phone       --> 1st Match
 --------------------------------------
   Jack   25    128736372
   Peter  26    987840392   --> 2nd Match
 --------------------------------------
 Sep2017:                   --> 3rd Match
 --------------------------------------
   Name   Age   Phone       --> 4th Match
 --------------------------------------
   Jared  21    874892032    
   Eric   24    847938427   --> 5th Match
 --------------------------------------
```

So in this case, I am choosing the second list element (`subMatch`) with `lindex`.

```
lindex [regexp -all -inline -- {\s+\-{2,}\s+(.*?)\s+\-{2,}\s+} $data] 1
```

However the result I got is like this, seems like it is matching from the beginning and end of the content:

```
  Name   Age   Phone
 --------------------------------------
  Jack   25    128736372
  Peter  26    987840392
 --------------------------------------
 Sep2017:
 --------------------------------------
  Name   Age   Phone
 --------------------------------------
  Jared  21    874892032
  Eric   24    847938427
```

My impression was regexp should match from the beginning and match sequentially to the end of the string, not sure why tcl regex is behaving like this? Am I missing something?

** The main thing I want to achieve here is to extract data between the dashed separator, the above data is just an example.

Expected result: a list that containing all matches

```
{ {Name   Age   Phone}      -->1st match 
  {Jack   25    128736372
   Peter  26    987840392}  -->2nd match
  {Sep2017:}                -->3rd match
  {Name   Age   Phone}      -->4th match
  {Jared  21    874892032
   Eric   24    847938427}  -->5th match
}
```

***UPDATE:***
I have slightly changed my tcl regex as below, to include the lookahead and the suggestion by @glenn:

```
regexp -all -inline -expanded -- {\s+?-{2,}\s+?(.*?)(?=\s+?-{2,}\s+?)} $data
```

The result I got (10 submatches):

```
{ {----------------------
   Name   Age   Phone}      -->1st match
  {Name   Age   Phone}      -->2nd match
  {----------------------
   Jack   25    128736372
   Peter  26    987840392}  -->3rd match
  {Jack   25    128736372
   Peter  26    987840392}  -->4th match
  {----------------------
   Sep2017:}                -->5th match
  {Sep2017:}                -->6th match
    ...
    ...
}
```

It is pretty close to the expected result, but I still want to figure out how to use regex to perfectly match the expected 5 submatches.

Comment: Tcl regular expressions, unlike perl's, are either completely greedy or completely non-greedy, and that choice is made by the **first** quantifier seen.  You need to carefully read the ["Matching" section of the `re_syntax` man page](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M95). The leading `\s+` is setting the greedy preference for the whole regex. If you change that to `\s+?` you'll get *closer* to your desired result, but only the odd-numbered submatches. This is because the regex is *consuming* the 2nd line of hyphens, so the next attempt no longer has a 1st line of hyphens.

Comment: The key sentence in the documentation link I provided is this: "A branch has the same preference as the first quantified atom in it which has a preference."

Comment: @glennjackman: Thanks for your suggestion. The result now is pretty close to the expected one, but I still want to figure out how to perfectly match in 5 submatches. You can see the updated result in "UPDATE" section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expression matching is not a good tool for this kind of problem. You're much better off with some kind of line filter.

A regular expression-based filter, closely matched to your example lines:

```
set f [open data.txt]
while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
    if {[regexp {:} $line]} continue
    if {![regexp {\d} $line]} continue
    puts $line
}
close $f
```

Rationale: only month name lines have colons, header lines and separators have no digits in them.

A filter that doesn't rely as much on regular expressions:

```
set f [open data.txt]
set skip 4
while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
    if {$skip < 1} {
        if {[regexp {\-{2,}} $line]} {
            set skip 4
        } else {
            puts $line
        }
    } else {
        incr skip -1
    }
}
close $f
```

This code reads every line, skips four lines at the beginning of each month, and resets the skip to 4 when a line of dashes interrupts the data.

(Note: the expression `\-{2,}` makes it look like the dash is special in a regular expression and needs to be escaped for that reason. Actually, it's because if the dash is the first character in the expression, the `regexp` command tries to interpret it as a switch. `regexp -- {-{2,}} ...` would work too but looks even stranger, I think.)

**ETA** (see comment): to get data between separators (i.e. just filter out the separators), try this:

```
set f [open data.txt]
while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
    if {![regexp {\-{2,}} $line]} {
        puts $line
    }
}
close $f
```

Or:

```
package require fileutil

::fileutil::foreachLine line data.txt {
    if {![regexp {\-{2,}} $line]} {
        puts $line
    }
}
```

This should also work:

```
regsub -all -line {^\s+-{2,}.*(\n|\Z)} $data {}
```

Enabling newline-sensitive matching, this matches and removes all lines consisting only of whitespace, dashes, optional non-newlines and either a newline character or the end-of-outer-string.

To collect a list of matches rather than just printing filtered lines:

```
set matches {}
set matchtext {}
::fileutil::foreachLine line data.txt {
    if {![regexp {\-{2,}} $line]} {
        append matchtext $line\n
    } else {
        lappend matches $matchtext
        set matchtext {}
    }
}
```

After running this, the variable `matches` contains a list whose items are contiguous lines between separators.

Another way to to the same thing:

```
::textutil::splitx $data {(?n)^\s+-{2,}.*(?:\n|\Z)}
```

(It also adds an empty element at the end of the list, which is easy enough to remove if it is a problem.)

Documentation:
[< (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[>= (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[append](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/append.htm),
[close](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/close.htm),
[continue](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/continue.htm),
[fileutil (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html),
[gets](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/gets.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm),
[package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[textutil (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/textutil/textutil.html),
[while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)

Comment: The above data is just an example. If i would like to extract data between the dashed separator, how could I achieve that? Please advise.

Comment: @user3635458: added a couple of suggestions.

Comment: I don't want to filter out the dash character. I wanted to extract the words in between every '-' separator, like what I have just added under 'Expected result'. I know this could be done by processing line-by-line, but my intention is to use regexp to do the extraction. Thanks.

Comment: @TattEhian: added a solution for this too at the end (it differs from your expected result in that the August tag is included.